How to reshape image tensor in pytorch
I am playing with the MNIST dataset, where each image is represented as a grayscale row of length 784, and I want to reformat it as 28x28:
DIM = int(len(features)**0.5)
X_train_tensor = torch.tensor(X_train_aug[features].values).float()
X_train_tensor = X_train_tensor.view(len(X_train_tensor), 1, DIM, DIM) # Batch Size, Channels, Height, Width

Which produces the following error when I feed it to the model:
ValueError: Expected input batch_size (1) to match target batch_size (42000).

I know I have 420k rows in the data set, and I am trying to feed it as a single batch. But somehow it seems the model thinks the entire tensor is a batch of size 1? Probably my .view above is wrong, but how do I fix it?
